# Can someone simplify to me what Patrick Meighan says In Ted 2?

Tags: ted-2

In *Ted 2* Patrick Meighan (Morgan Freeman) says the following words (around the 1:21 mark):

> You know why you lost this case? It can't be argued by reason. The precedent it sets would affect the public directly. And unfortunately, the public doesn't judge by reason. It judges by emotion. And you can't appeal an emotional conviction.

What does this mean? Can anyone simplify those words to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patrick is saying that the court case can't be won with Logic. People are dumb, emotional creatures. To win, you have to give people an emotional reason. People (the jury) have to care, it doesn't matter if it makes sense.

The Appeal part means that a verdict based on emotions leaves the prosecution or defendant without any legal reason for appeal. A Jury's verdict is incredibly hard to appeal. Next to impossible. An appeal based on factual or legal errors by the prosecution or judge is easier, and common.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you properly. One wins case when it addresses people's emotions? Why does Patrick further says that you can't appeal an emotional conviction? Is it because an appeal would mean that you hit on their already established emotions?

Comment: @haris yes, and I've updated my answer